# when adding a second tabpanel to navbarpage i cannot see the data anymore

Tags: r, shiny

I´m trying to add a second tabpanel to my application and the webpage is properly displayed but the data is not loaded anymore.

## app.r

```
library(shiny)
source('myui.R', local = TRUE)
source('myserver.R')

shinyApp(
  ui     = myui,
  server = myserver
)
```

## myui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(phyloseq)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

    myui <-       navbarPage("GLOBAL",id = "navbar",
                  tabPanel("iAlpha Diversity",
                           titlePanel("Alpha diversity"),

                           sidebarLayout(

                             sidebarPanel(

                               radioButtons("taxa", label = h3("Select taxonomic rank"),
                                            choices = list("Phylum" = "Phylum", 
                                                           "Class"    = "Class", 
                                                           "Order"    = "Order",
                                                           "Family"   = "Family",
                                                           "Genus"    = "Genus",
                                                           "Species"  = "Species"), 
                                            selected = "Genus"),

                               radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Select ecological index"),
                                            choices = list("Observed" = "Observed", 
                                                           "Chao1"    = "Chao1", 
                                                           "se.chao1" = "se.chao1",
                                                           "Ace"      = "ACE",
                                                           "Shannon"  = "Shannon",
                                                           "Simpson"  = "Simpson"), 
                                            selected = "Shannon"),

                               radioButtons("sdata", label = h3("Select metadata"),
                                            choices = list("gender" = "gender", 
                                                           "time"    = "time", 
                                                           "CO2" = "CO2",
                                                           "H2O"      = "H20"),
                                            selected = "time"),
                               downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download current plot'),
                               hr(),

                               br()),

                             mainPanel(

                               tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                           tabPanel("Summary", value=1, verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                                           tabPanel("Plot", value=2, plotOutput("plot")),
                                           tabPanel("Table",value=3, tableOutput("table"))
                               )

                             )
                           )
```

If i try to add the code below (a second tabpanel) the page will load but no data will be rendered. I have commented the code below.

```
                 ),
                  tabPanel(id="Ordinations",
                           titlePanel("Ordinations"),

                           # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                            sidebarLayout(

                             # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                             sidebarPanel(

                                radioButtons("test", label = h3("Select other"),
                                          choices = list("Phylum" = "Phylum", 
                                                            "Class"    = "Class", 
                                                          "Order"    = "Order",
                                                          "Family"   = "Family",
                                                          "Genus"    = "Genus",
                                                          "Species"  = "Species"), 
                                           selected = "Genus"),
                              hr(),

                                br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing ----
                            br()
                                  ),

                           mainPanel(
                               # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
                               tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",

                                           tabPanel("Plot2", value=1, plotOutput("plot2"))


                                          )

                            )
                     )
                  )
)
```

## myserver.R

```
myserver <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <-reactiveValues(data = NULL, taxo=NULL)

  # Observe click on button and load corresponding table
  observeEvent(input$taxa, {
    taxoRLD <- readRDS(paste0("data/alphadiv_",input$taxa,".rds"))
    alpha = estimate_richness(taxoRLD, split = TRUE, measures = c("Observed", "Chao1", "ACE", "Shannon", "Simpson", "RecSimpson"))
    alpha$sample=as.character(row.names(alpha))
    a <- melt(alpha)
    colnames(a)[2] <- "metric" 
    a <- merge(a,sample_data(taxoRLD),by.x="sample",by.y="row.names")
    values$data <- a
    values$taxo <- taxoRLD
  })

  d <- reactive({input$radio
    a
  })

  s <- reactive({input$sdata
    s
  })

  # Generate a plot of the data ----

  # Create plot
  plotInput <- reactive({

    a <- values$data
    b <- a[a$metric == input$radio,]
    b <- droplevels.data.frame(b)
    #observe(print(b))
    p1 <- ggplot(b, aes(x=b[,input$sdata], y=value)) +
      geom_boxplot(aes(fill=b[,input$sdata])) +
      scale_colour_manual(values=hmcol) +
      labs(x="",y="Value",colour=input$sdata) +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      ggtitle(b$metric) +
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=8)) +
      scale_colour_manual(name = a$metric,values=hmcol)+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0,size=10)) +  
      theme(legend.text=element_text(size=10)) +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(input$sdata,nrow = 15)) 

    if (input$sdata != "Site") {
      p1 <- p1 + facet_wrap(~ Site    , nrow=1) 
    }
    p1    
  })

  #print plot
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput())
  }, height = 800, width = 1200,res=90)

  #print plot
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput())
  }, height = 800, width = 1200,res=90)

  # Generate a summary of the data ----
  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    values$taxo
  })

  # Generate an HTML table view of the data ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$data
  })

  # Download data
  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste(input$taxa, '.png', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      ggsave(file, plot = plotInput(), width = 12, height = 10, dpi=100, units= "in", device = "png")
    })

}
```

So just to make it clear, the idea is to add a second tab without loosing the information loaded in the first tab. So by defautl the first tab should load all the data as usual. The tab and tabnales are properly created and also the tabsetpanel.

Not sure what is wrong ?

Comment: You have same `ids` already rendered once, hence wont show. Try changing the `tabPanel` names to unique once, also check the rest of divs

Comment: Hi, which ids ??

Comment: `tabPanel("Summary")` is repeated twice, so as the other ones

Comment: Ok got it,
Added in myui.R as an example:
``tabPanel("Plot2", value=1, plotOutput("plot2"))``


in myserver.R


``output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    print(plotInput())
  }, height = 800, width = 1200,res=90) ``

Works well, thanks

Comment: Answer the question yourself plz, so others can reference it too